# Does grpc++_reflection library come with vcpkg install grpc for x86-windows?

Tags: x86, grpc, vcpkg

I installed grpc c++ via vcpkg and trying to cmake the helloworld example project for Win32 platform.
It fails because cmake can't find the grpc++_reflection library which is liked to the example project. It seems like there is no grpc++_reflection library installed for x86-windows with vcpkg. Is it supposed to be like this or is there any way to solve this situation?

I was able to build the same project for x64.

## What I've tried to install

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
$ ./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
$ ./vcpkg integrate install
$ vcpkg install grpc
```

Comment: Yusuke Kadowaki submitted a report and patch here. Thank you.
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/17247

Comment: I'm encountering the same error with `x64-windows-static`, which wasn't mentioned in the original report. I've added a new issue report: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/21514